# Error when removing items from chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to get my chrome extension (service worker) to detect when a tab is open to add an object to storage and when a tab is closed to remove the corresponding item from storage. However I'm receiving an error on removal:

> Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of storage.remove([string|array] keys, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'keys': Value did not match any choice.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab)=>{
    if (changeInfo.title && tab.status == "complete") {
        try {
            chrome.storage.local.set({[tabId]:changeInfo})
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}); 

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId, removeInfo)=>{
    chrome.storage.local.remove([tabId]) <---- ERROR HERE
})
```

To make sure the content of the storage I also tried the following to make sure the storage has the object and the key to remove it with:

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId, removeInfo)=>{
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, (storage) => {
        console.log(storage)
        chrome.storage.local.remove([tabId])
    }) 
})
```

Been stuck on this for a while so any recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You are giving remove an array of keys (`[tabId]`), but [`Storage.removeItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) takes a single string representing a storage entry's key.

Try to replace
`chrome.storage.local.remove([tabId])`
with
`chrome.storage.local.remove(tabId)`

Comment: I tried that but received a different error message. 

 " Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of storage.remove([string|array] keys, optional function callback): No matching signature. "

Also as far as I know the square bracket converts the expression inside to a string. Judging by the error message and how storage.local.set() operates I dont think square bracket is the issue.

Comment: The square bracket are used to construct arrays like so : `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
When constructing an object, it allows you to parse a variable as a property string : `{[variable]: "bar"}`

Comment: No matching signature error is often known as a wrong type error, console.log your tabId before calling the remove function, it might not be a string

Comment: I see, tabId is a number data type and tabId.toString() seems to work. Thanks !